# Doubts on some notes on the co-area formula

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, self-learning

I am trying to read these notes on the co-area formula ( I wanted to understand better this [A "contorted" Fubini.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132738/a-contorted-fubini/4135366#comment8555360_4135366) ) :

[https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Coarea.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Coarea.pdf)

but already at page 3 I have some doubts. Lemma 1 reads:

[image]

My doubts:

- First of all I guess that "Euclidean spaces" here are intended as vector spaces with a positive definite scalar product and "Euclidean coordinates" are intended as coordinates w.r.t. an orthogonal bases. Is this correct ?
- Lemma 1.1. isn't it just the standard Singular Value Decomposition ? Is there any difference ?

Than in claims Eq. 1.4 :

[image]

I understand that it lacks a bit of context this equation, but A should be the surjective linear map. I am not sure why:

- $J_A$ depends on $x,y$ if the Jacobian of a linear map is just a constant ? Am I missing something or is it a typo ?

Comment: Down votes  without explanation are not welcome in this site as far as I understand ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the meaning of *Euclidean spaces* and *Euclidean coordinates* appear to be what you say and the Lemma is just the singular value decomposition, stated with change of coordinates instead of a product of matrices.
- (1.4) is the general form appearing in the coarea formula. In the case where $A$ is linear, the dependence $J_A(x,y)$ is trivial in the sense that it is constant, nothing mysterious here. The function $f(x)=1$ is a function of $x$, just a constant one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer